# App install says "Application Not Installed"

Tags: android

I am developing an app and I am trying to share it with a couple of friends so they can test it. I created a key using this http://www.androiddevelopment.org/tag/apk/ method. The app installs on phone without a problem, but when I actually click on the icon to launch the app, it says "Application Not Installed". This is super weird considering the fact that I see it in my list of applications and there is an icon in my app drawer. What is happening? I answer the question at the bottom of the page. This is the new XML file that works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name = ".SQLView" android:label ="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.test.SQLVIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />      
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name = ".Add_Flashcard" android:label ="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.test.ADD_FLASHCARD" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />      
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name = ".Flashcards_List" android:label ="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.test.FLASHCARDS_LIST" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />      
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name = ".Edit_Flashcard" android:label ="@string/app_name"
                android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.test.EDIT_FLASHCARD" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />      
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name = ".Decks_List" android:label ="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.test.DECKS_LIST" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />      
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Make sure your activity is specified correctly.  In your manifest above, it is listed as `com.example.test.MainActivity`, but since you redacted your package name at the top, I suspect it is actually in a different package. Usually this causes an force close, but it is something to check.

Comment: did you try sharing is with default keystore. Also does your friend device have there setting enabled: "Install from unknown source"

Comment: Have you changed the package name in the past? Have you tried to remove the app completely from the device first?

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by "I deleted this" for the `package` element?

Comment: I changed the activities to match the main package that I actually renamed. Furthermore, I tried using the default keystore and the device has the option checked "Install from uknown source". It is still showing "Application not installed" when I click on the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what the problem was. When I wanted to export the app directly through Eclipse(also adding the keystore and everything) I went into the packages options and I renamed the package through the options. That apparently did not rename everything and it was also inserting .R into all of my classess. Also, when you rename the package, the package import in your classess will stay the same. When renaming, be sure that EVERYTHING is changed appropriately, as apparently this is a known bug in Eclipse. This was in turn causing that weird error because of the different packages that did not match the packages inside... Super weird.